# Couldn't configure facebook LoginButtonDelegate in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, swift2

I need to integrate facebook login in iOS(8.1, swift-2.3).
in pod file add

```
pod 'FacebookCore'
pod 'FacebookLogin'
pod 'FacebookShare'
```

in view controller file import

```
import FacebookCore
import FacebookLogin
```

I have added facebook button

```
let fbLoginButton = LoginButton(readPermissions: [ .PublicProfile ])
fbLoginButton.frame = CGRect(x: 25, y: 400, width: AppSettings.screenWidth-50, height: 30)
fbLoginButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()        
self.view.addSubview(fbLoginButton)
fbLoginButton.delegate = self
```

But I couldn't configure `LoginButtonDelegate`. it shows error.

[image: error in LoginButtonDelegate]

How can I fix this one

Answer (score 1):

You implementation of facebook delegate method is wrong. There should be space between **func** and **loginButtonDidCompleteLogin**